# Como verificar se uma frase/string contém palavras de uma lista em Kotlin

Tags: string, lista, kotlin

Estou tendo problemas com o operador **in**, quando eu tenho apenas um **operando** eu consigo facilmente verificar se uma determinada palavra está contida em uma lista, por exemplo:

```
fun main(){
    val cores = listOf(
            "branco",
            "azul",
            "verde"
    )
    val cor = "azul"

    if(cor in cores){
        println("Está contido!")
    }
    else{
        println("Não está contido!")
    }
}
```

Mas quando tenho **vários operando** para verificar (como em uma frase por exemplo) eu tenho o problema aonde ele verifica apenas a primeira palavra da frase, no python eu resolveria esse problema usando o **for** para percorrer cada palavra da frase, porém no Kotlin isso não funciona, mesmo se uma palavra da lista for a primeira a aparecer frase não funciona.

código:

```
fun main(){
    val cores = listOf(
        "branco",
        "azul",
        "verde"
    )
    val frase = "Eu gosto da cor azul"

    for(palavra in frase){
        if(palavra.toString() in cores){
            println("Está contido!")
        }
        else{
            println("Não está contido!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você está fazendo não faz sentido. O que você tem que fazer é usar o método [contains](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html) para verificar se uma palavra existe em uma string.

Como por exemplo:

```
fun main() {
    val cores = listOf(
            "branco",
            "azul",
            "verde"
    )
    val frase = "Eu gosto da cor azul"
    
    for(cor in cores){
        if(frase.contains(cor)){
            println("A cor '${cor}' Está contido!")
        }
        else{
            println("A cor '${cor}' Não está contido!")
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Só por curiosidade, ao fazer `for(palavra in frase)` o for irá passar por cada caractere da `string` `frase` ao invés de cada palavra.*

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado, funcionou aqui, eu não conhecia esse método, muito bom!